# AFNetworking client subclass not parsing responses

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I was trying to implement an AFNetworking client by subclassing AFHTTPClient and setting base path

```
#define WineAPIBaseURLString @"http://localhost:3000/"
@implementation WineAPIClient

+(id)sharedInstance{
  static WineAPIClient *__sharedInstance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    __sharedInstance = [[WineAPIClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WineAPIBaseURLString]];
});
return __sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
 self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if(self){
    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
}

return self;
}

@end
```

Now calling the client within my view controller is giving me weird results. For example the following code:

```
[[WineAPIClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"wines"
                               parameters:nil
                               success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

                               }
                               failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"Error fetching wines!");
                                        NSLog(@"%@",error);
                               }];
```

It's logging into console a bunch of numbers:

```
2013-03-11 16:25:36.411 AFNetworking4[1934:1260b] GET 'http://localhost:3000/wines'
2013-03-11 16:25:36.430 AFNetworking4[1934:f803] <5b0a2020 7b0a2020 2020225f 5f76223a    20302c0a 20202020 225f6964 223a2022 35313131 35656235 37356265 35383766 3034303...
2013-03-11 16:25:36.429 AFNetworking4[1934:13003] 200 'http://localhost:3000/wines' [0.0173 s]
```

How can I correct the client to parse correctly JSON?? Are there any mistakes on client implementation?.

One thing to note is that the exactly same URI is working correctly when not using the custom client.

I.E:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/wines"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

I'm using the 0.10.1 branch of AFNetworking (I must support 4.x devices, so I can't upgrade...).

Any ideas how to correct that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, that's right... I was receiving NSData instead of parsed JSON. Completely missed docs info regarding this part

*These content types are only returned as the response object for requests when 1) 
   the HTTP  client has registered the appropriate AFHTTPRequestOperation subclass with -
   registerHTTPOperationClass:, and 2) the request Accept HTTP header is appropriate for the
   content type requested. Not doing this may result in getting an NSData instance of the
   success     or failure callback blocks of methods like getPath:parameters:success:failure.
   So to work with JSON data, for example, do [client registerHTTPOperationClass: 
   [AFJSONRequestOperation class]] and [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept"
   value:@"application/json"] when initializing the HTTP client.*

So, the fix was simply adding **Accept application/json** default header to the client.

Answer (score 1):

The `AFJSONParamterEncoding` only affects parameters you pass with a request. It looks like you're receiving data encoded as NSData. You could try to create an NSString with `initWithData` and then log that. You also may want to make sure your client is returning actual JSON. In ruby this would probably require a `to_json` method.